# Display most recent posts in category with Twenty Ten theme widget

Tags: posts, categories, sidebar, theme-twenty-ten

I am fairly new to WordPress, and I would like to have a list of the most recent posts in a certain category appear in a right-hand panel (I can do this with all posts, but not specific categories)

I am using the Twenty Ten theme, on wordpress.com. I have found the following code, but unsure if or where this can be added:

```
<ul>
<?php $recent = new WP_Query("cat=10&showposts=5"); while($recent->have_posts()) : $recent->the_post();?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest way, a plugin:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/category-posts/

Comment: The installation instructions say "Upload it to the plugins folder of your blog." I am not sure if this is possible on the free version?

Comment: Ok, found out I cannot do this. I may have to use a custom server.

Comment: oh, you're using WordPress.com. Sorry. I've never customized a WP.com blog.

Comment: I have got a wordpress.org server, and I installed the plugin but it only shows "Uncategorized" in the categories dropdown..

Answer (score 0):

You are using wordpress.com. You cannot modify your Theme template files, or upload Plugins. You are limited to the Plugins available via `Dashboard -> Plugins`.